# Что означает этот синтаксис if? C++

Tags: c++, if, auto

Читал про std::oprional и наткнулся на такой кусок кода:

```
if (auto ostr = maybe_create_hello(); ostr) // Это кто? (Who?) :/
    std::cout << "ostr " << *ostr << '\n';  
else  
    std::cout << "ostr is null\n";
```

Не могу понять что происходит в условии if. Первая часть с auto понятна - прямо в if инициализируется переменная ostr значением функции. Но после ; ostr - что это? И как if проверяет данное выражение?

Comment: А потом проверяет значение этой переменной `ostr` - оно приводится к `true` (тогда выполняется первая ветвь) или к `false` (тогда выполняется ветвь `else`).

Comment: @Harry А что если оставить в if() только auto ostr = maybe_create_hello()? Проверит ли if значение ostr после присвоения?

Comment: По-моему будет ошибка, т.к. компилятор не догадается что присвоение нужно будет отделить от сравнения и определения переменной.

Comment: Если оставить только то, что вы предлагаете - это как в `for` объединить инициализацию и условие. Написать можно, работать не будет...

Comment: @Harry а есть ли у такого синтаксиса if название какое-то? Хочу погуглить про этот способ использования if побольше

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
if (auto ostr = maybe_create_hello(); ostr)
```

Вышеприведенный фрагмент кода эквивалентен следующему

```
{
    auto ostr = maybe_create_hello();
    if (ostr) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Сперва он объявляет переменную `ostr`, инициализируя ее значением, возвращенным функцией `maybe_create_hello` (являющимся, как я понимаю, `std::optional<std::string>` или `std::optional<const char*>`).

А далее, так как результат выражения, переданного в качестве условия оператора if должен приводиться к `bool`, пытается привести `ostr` к `bool`, что успешно осуществляется, так как для `std::optional` перегружено приведение к `bool`, возвращающее `true`, если объект содержит значение, и `false`, если не содержит.

Документация к классу `std::optional`: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Документация к оператору `if`: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)